# How to use variable for object key c#

Tags: c#, object

Im trying to use the variable OrderBy as an object key.

```
string OrderBy = "Entity";

output = new object[] { new { OrderBy = "asc" } };
```

Current output:

```
"orderBy":[{"OrderBy":"asc" }]
```

Desired output:

```
"orderBy":[{"Entity":"asc" }]
```

Comment: `OrderBy` is the name of the property so when you serialize it, it will just show `OrderBy`. Why do you want to get the desired output, what are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This:

```
output = new object[] { new { OrderBy = "asc" } };
```

Does not give this:

```
"orderBy":[{"OrderBy":"asc" }]
```

As "output". You must be serializing to JSON somehow. The best answer will depend how you are doing that - You can't dynamically set property names in C# (okay, okay, you can with reflection/emit or dynamic), something like this:

```
dynamic dynamicObject = new ExpandoObject();
(dynamicObject AS IDictionary<String,Object>)[OrderBy] = "asc";
// Then serialize as you are doing now
```

But that's sketchy and you shouldn't... You should use something like JObject, assuming you are using Newtonsoft.JSON:

```
JObject jsonObject = new JObject;
jsonObject[Orderby] = "asc"
var output = jsonObject.ToString();
```

There will be other ways with other serializers, if you say which one you are using...

Answer (score 1):

Dynamic keys can be obtained by using Dictionary. And as you want to have array of them, you need to place them in List<> for example. The code become a little bit messy, but this will give you resluts you want

```
string OrderBy = "Entity";
var dict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
dict[OrderBy] = "asc";
List<Dictionary<string, string>> list = new List<Dictionary<string, string>>();
list.Add(dict);
var output = new { orderBy = list };
var str = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(output);
Console.WriteLine(str);
```

Answer (score -2):

You will just have to do it this way:

`var output = new object[] { new { Entity = "asc" } };`

You can't replace the property name of an anonymous object with a variable, as far as I know.